# How to find installed conda path for tensorflow package in R?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I tried to run keras package from R in RStudio as shown in this [tutorial](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/). However, I get stuck by loading data from mnist dataset with the command `mnist <- dataset_mnist()` as I get the error:

```
Error: Python module tensorflow.python.keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\python.exe
libpython:      C:/PROGRA~3/ANACON~1/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1
version:        3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.16.2
tensorflow:     [NOT FOUND]

python versions found: 
 C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\python.exe
 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

It seems not to find tensorflow package, which is already installed as `installed.packages()` shows:

```
           Package      LibPath                                              Version        Priority
keras      "keras"      "C:/Users/NikolasVarela/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" "2.2.4.1.9001" NA      
tensorflow "tensorflow" "C:/Users/NikolasVarela/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" "1.13.1"       NA
```

I previously manually installed Anaconda for python 3.7 and downgraded in the Anaconda Navigator to 3.6 as shown in [this](https://www.udemy.com/deep-learning-und-ai/) udemy tutorial as mentioned that tensorflow only runs on python 3.6. After that I downloaded all needed packages including tensorflow and keras on the anaconda navigator. I assume that this manuell change makes the problem in finding tensorflow. But I didn't find a solution on the web.

Further, I tried to set the path of the `dataset_mnist()` function as mentioned in the [description](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/keras/versions/2.2.4.1/topics/dataset_mnist). However, I don't find a `~/.keras/datasets` on my directory. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I finally resolved it as follows:

1. Downgrade to python 3.6 in the conda environment (you've already mentioned it, but I'm showing how here): `conda create -y --name r-tensorflow tensorflow-gpu keras-gpu python=3.6.8`. (Note: I'm not sure it is necessary to install the keras-gpu package here.)
2. Restart R session since it has probably already initialized with the wrong version of Python.
3. Force R to use the conda environment with the downgraded Python: `keras::use_condaenv("r-tensorflow", required = TRUE)`.
4. Now it should work. Try the following if you don't mind downloading the MNIST database:

   ```
   library(keras)
   mnist <- dataset_mnist()
   ```

PS. I've first tried installing via R as follows:

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras(method = c("conda"),
              conda = "auto", version = "default", tensorflow = "gpu")
```

PPS. Of course you need to already have Python, Anaconda/Miniconda, CUDA and cuDNN installed as well as some other requirements. I'm assuming you have and that you don't have version conflicts.